# Return a 404 for all requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a development version of a website that I want to hide/disable. But I don't want to delete the files for the moment. I also don't want to redirect requests to somewhere else. I just want to respond to the requests for that website with a HTTP 404.

How should I do it?

I am using Apache and .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oldsite/?$ http://www.domain.com/errorpage.html [r=301,nc]
```

This is a little gentler than a hard 404.  Otherwise you can change the response code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If I replace r=301 with a r=404 then, will the user agent see it? and think that the page isn't there?

Comment: Yep.  It's a response like the directory doesn't even exist.